# Listview at the bottom that i have designed for android doesnt show up entirely

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio, scrollview

You can see the code below that belongs layout design.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/profilePic2"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/feed_item_profile_pic"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/feed_item_profile_pic"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter" >
                    </ImageView>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_profile_info_padd" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/name2"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/feed_item_profile_name"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/timestamp2"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/timestamp"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/feed_item_timestamp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="TextView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/textCategory2"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textStyle="normal|bold"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/content2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_top"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/contentImage2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:cropToPadding="false"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/bg_parent_rounded_corner"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:isScrollContainer="false"
                    android:keepScreenOn="false"
                    android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
                    android:verticalScrollbarPosition="defaultPosition"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:text="@string/yorumlar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/textView"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <ListView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/comList"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
                        android:clipChildren="false"
                        android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

We can see details of the post showing up top of the screen, comments are at the bottom of the screen. Comments doesnt show up entirely despite of scrollview included listview and i have “layout_height:wrap_content”. First comment showing up but else doesnt show up with scroll.

Thanks for the answers

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FOD4.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change following things to display the list:

1. change the height of root linear layout from wrap content to match parent.

   ```
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   ```
2. do the same thing to scroll view

   ```
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   ```

3 now change the height of listview, I have given android:layout_height="500dp" this. You can adjust this with your requirement.

NOTE: List view will not work inside scrollview without giving static height. So you have to give height as 400..500dp or you can remove scrollview.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this solution

Comment: Welcome İbrahim Ürüker :)